# Ajax request -> request.readyState problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot execute php on this page, because the content is stored in a mysql database, but I can put javascript/jquery/ajax.

I need it to get a few details so that the page can be dynamic. So I built a php script that will output the data it needs in a string like this:

```
 string=value|string2=value here|string3=value there
```

It is on the same domain, so not cross urls...

Here is the ajax I'm trying to use, it is code I have on another website I created a few years ago, But I cannot get it to work, I'll share the code and response I am seeing below.

Code I load on the page out of the database:

```
function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}


function cpf(tpg) {
    request = createRequest();
    if(request == null) {
        alert("Unable to Create Request");
        return;
    }
    var nocache = new Date();
    var url = "/pull_data.php?t=" + tpg;
    url = url + "&stopIEcache="+ nocache;

    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.onreadystatechange = showtpage();
    request.send(null);
    return true;
}

function showtpage() {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            detailDiv = document.getElementById("showPageHere");
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        } else {
            alert('Req Failed...');
        }
    } else {
        alert('request failed.' + request.readyState);
    }
}
```

I put a link on the page that calls it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(cpf(customdata)) {alert('ran and customdata = ' + customdata);} else {alert('pow, did not work... hmm');}">Click here to run code</a><br />
<div id="showPageHere"></div>
```

customdata is set elsewhere, and it does alert me of that data, so it is populated...

the second alert is from the code, it has this:

```
request failed. 1
```

so the response is 1

Do you see why it is not working?

Because the php file it calls is on the same url, I am lost as to why it is not working.

I appreciate you helping me find the error, I've worked on this all this past weekend, like over 20 hours, and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: change `request.onreadystatechange = showtpage();` to `request.onreadystatechange = showtpage;` -

Comment: Okay, I did that and now it returns:
request failed. 2

so now not 1, but 2

Comment: well, you're not waiting for readystate to get to 4 ... you just alert an error if the request is in progress ... perhaps familiarise yourself with xmlhttprequest [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: ah got it. Thank you. I see that now.